# Predestination and human knowledge

Tags: denomination-survey, predestination, afterlife

Is there any denomination that claim to know it is possible for humans to know where a human is predestined to go after death?

Comment: In terms of specific individuals? Or in general (If you put your trust in God you will be saved)?

Comment: In terms of a specific place? Or in general (the saved will go to be with the Lord and those who are not saved will go into eternal darkness/cutting off)?  Your question is somewhat vague, Helena. And what research have you done into this subject that leads you to ask this question? If you want a well-thought out and considered answer you need to present a well-thought out and considered question.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous regarding the word 'human'. Are you asking if any group of persons claim to know what is the destiny of humanity as such ? Or are you asking if any group of persons claim to be able to predict the destiny of a single, individual, specific human being who can be identified and named ?

Comment: Do the answers in this question help?  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/48322/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-belief-that-people-do-not-go-to-heaven-or-hel

Comment: Would it be appropriate to shorten "claim to know it is possible for humans to know where a human is predestined..." to "claim it is possible for humans to know where a human is predestined..."? It makes the question less convoluted but should still capture what you are asking, right? Or even just "claim it is possible to know where a human is predestined..."?

Comment: Knowing the "predestination"-from beginning to the  end- is "mystery" to us, human. It is God's "doing"  in the eternal "behind-the scene."  It is the sovereign prerogative of God. And even Calvin, the proponent of "predestination" warns against delving into the subject (Inst. III)., for that matter, all  denomination -church- who makes such claims should  heed the warning.  Jesus indicates it is knowable -"My sheep hear my voice, and I know them, and they follow me. I give them eternal life, and they will never perish. (Jn. 10:27,28a), and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the term "predestination" in your question specifically refers to God's choice of individuals for **blessed eternal life** or **eternal damnation**, after death, and with that understanding, I would like to make short comments:

First, is it knowable? The answer is a "binary" one: if you are "in" then you are "not
out." And the best place to find the answer in the Scripture:

**Jesus says**,

- "**My sheep hear my voice**, and I know them and **they follow me** (Jn 10:27).
- "And I have **other sheep**(you and I) that are not of this fold. I must bring them also, and **they will listen to my voice** (v 16);
- "When he has brought out all his own, he goes before them, and **the sheep follow him**, for **they know his voice**. **A stranger they will not follow, but they will flee from him**, for they do not know the voice of strangers.” (v4-5).
- "Truly, truly, I say to you, **unless one is born of water and the Spirit**, he cannot enter the kingdom of God. That which is born of the flesh is flesh, and that which is born of the Spirit is spirit. ....**The wind blows where it wishes, and you hear its sound,** but you do not know where it comes from or where it goes. So it is with everyone who is born of the Spirit.”

So, it is **knowable**, and the knowing is **between you and the Lord, a personal thing**. And **NO denomination or any human can claim to know for certain**.

**The Holy Spirit says,**

- Romans 8:16 -"T**he Spirit himself bears witness with our spirit that we are children of God."**

So, it is knowable and knowing comes from your inner person, because the Holy Spirit abides in you as "**Parakletos**" (Πνεύματος), and works within you. Paul says, "can you NOT know when He is in you? (Paul uses an analogy of being drunk with wine (Eph. 5:18.)

- Scripture witnesses that, where ever He, the Holy Spirit appears, i.e, Gen. 1:2, a new order and creation happens, and changes occur. When believers in faith yield to Him, they will see  He "bear witness"- slow but radical changes in your prayer, devotion, and attitude to others Because, your world view changes, so the value system, and purpose of life, etc.  You will become "seeking His kingdom and His righteousness first", etc. You will repent and confess your sin that is the sure way a child can enjoy the peace and love of God in your life.

**More Texts to meditate:**

- the Parables- the Pearl merchant & the treasure hunter (Mt.13:44, 45-46).
- "Jesus says, "You are the light" implies the darkness will flee from you and in your presence, and "you the salt" - people associate with you will see what difference you bring into their life.

**Conclusion**

Yes, it is knowable, NO one else can claim to know for sure, but you and people around you will notice something going on with you,  and the **Lord knows YOU are His**, **that's all that matter. *Blessings to you!***

PS: I have a comment might you find interesting: "what is the role of our will"  the link:{[here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/what-is-the-will-of-a-man-and-what-is-its-role-in-our-walk-with-god/48135#48135)}